# Prove that $4^n-3^n\gt 2n^2$ for all $n\ge 3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, induction

I found this problem in a textbook, I confirmed it works when n = 3, and followed up with the inductive step,
$$4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}\gt2(n+1)^2$$
but I'm stuck at
$$4^n\cdot4-3^n\cdot3\gt2n^2+4n+2$$
Induction is a new thing for me, so please excuse any mistakes, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $2n^2<4^n-3^n$ and $n\geq 3$.

\begin{align}
2(n+1)^2&=2n^2+4n+2\\
&<8n^2\\
&<4(4^n-3^n)\\
&=4^{n+1}-4\cdot 3^n\\
&<4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Solution without induction.

By the Lagrange's theorem there is $\theta\in(0,1)$ for which also by Bernoulli we obtain:
$$4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}=\frac{4^{n+1}-3^{n+1}}{4-3}=(n+1)(3+\theta)^{n+1}>$$
$$>(n+1)3^{n+1}>(n+1)(1+2(n+1))>2(n+1)^2.$$